# how to install qr code library in php

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP & would like to use PHP QR Code library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/ I download zip file but don't know where to put these contents in Linux for my PHP to recognize.

Can I keep them anywhere or whats the good practice on where to put them & install?

Thanks

Comment: What is your PHP application structure? You can create a nested folder called "lib" or so. From a page you can include it by including it.

Comment: I just have one simple PHP page deployed in /var/www/html & nothing else.

Comment: I posted an answer that should work if your apache server is well configured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the INSTALL file, it seems as easy as:

- unzip the files in your lib folder (/var/www/lib/qrlib for instance)
- From the PHP page, include the qrlib file
- And you are done

Here is an example of code that should work if your PHP page is in the /var/www folder. Write this code in the /var/www/qrtest.php file, and try to access it from your browser.

```
<?php

//include only that one, rest required files will be included from it
include "./lib/qrlib/qrlib.php"

//write code into file, Error corection lecer is lowest, L (one form: L,M,Q,H)
//each code square will be 4x4 pixels (4x zoom)
//code will have 2 code squares white boundary around 

QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)', 'test.png', 'L', 4, 2);

//same as above but outputs file directly into browser (with appr. header etc.)
//all other settings are default
//WARNING! it should be FIRST and ONLY output generated by script, otherwise
//rest of output will land inside PNG binary, breaking it for sure
QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');

//show benchmark
QRtools::timeBenchmark();

//rebuild cache
QRtools::buildCache();

//code generated in text mode - as a binary table
//then displayed out as HTML using Unicode block building chars :)
$tab = $qr->encode('PHP QR Code :)');
QRspec::debug($tab, true);

?>
```

Comment: I followed above steps but when I hit the php in browser, nothing gets displayed

Comment: Where is your default php file? And are you able to access it?

Comment: I followed above steps but when I hit the php in browser, nothing gets displayed. I checked logs & can see below error:  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'QRcode' (T_STRING). It does not reqcognize the QRCode function at all

Comment: It is probably because the include path is not good. Can you show me the full path of the "qrtest.php" file you have AND the full path of the "qrlibrary.php" file

Comment: ok..I corrected the path & now I see error in browser "The image cannot be displayed as it contains error". Note that I need to show QR code directly in browser & so I kept only include line & QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)'); line but no luck, log has no errors now

Comment: Well if the error "The image cannot be displayed as it contains error" is displayed in your browser, it means that the library was included! I can't help you for the rest but from my understanding, it should download the file automatically, make sure that your browser doesn't prevent automatic file download.